# Moving multiple folders all at once in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Constantly at my shop, we are moving Outlook (or other email program) files between computers or Windows Installations, and sometimes, people have HUNDREDS of folders. Is there a quick way to move ALL the folders from multiple data files (`*.PST`) into one single file, without dragging each and every folder? No, I don't want to move the Inbox folder into the other Inbox folder for the quick move, I want something simple like selecting all folders and moving that way. Does such a method exist in any version of Outlook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no native tool in Outlook to perform this task (haven't investigated Outlook 2010 thoroughly)

You'll need a 3rd party tool to do this. The one I've used with success is SysTools PST Merge http://www.systoolsgroup.com/pst-merge.html

If you're doing this often, its commercial license will quickly pay for itself. (We had 20 users for whom to perform merges)

It has a trial mode which will merge the first 3 folders of any PST to demonstrate how it's working. It's not the speediest tool, and it's progress bars don't update very accurately, but it works. It will also let you discriminate between folders to merge e.g. just the Contacts or just the mail folders for example.